# Proving a definition?

Tags: functions

> If f is an invertible function with domain X and range Y, then
>
> $ f^{-1}\left(\,f(x)\,\right)=x$, for every ${\displaystyle x\in X.}$

The question from my textbook is:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ is an invertible function.Show that the inverse of
>   $f^{-1} is f$

How can I prove the definition itself?

Comment: No, the definition says that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$. What you have to prove, instead, is that $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$.

Comment: Or stated differently, you know that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$, but you want to show $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for every $x\in X$, we can apply $f$ to both sides:
$$
f(f^{-1}(f(x)))=f(x)\;\;\mbox{for every}\;\;x\in X
$$
As $f$ is invertible, $f(x)$ attains each value in $Y$ (it is surjective). Therefore we can substitute $y=f(x)$ and we get
$$
f(f^{-1}(y))=y\;\;\mbox{for every}\;\;y\in Y
$$
which means that $f$ is the inverse of $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well that isn't quite the definition, although it is extremely close. You need to show that $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$, but to do that you need only show that $f$ is a left and right inverse of $f^{-1}$, which by definition it is.